# Ports won't open on OCI subnet

Tags: oracle, networking, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using Oracle Cloud (free tier) and the ports will not open. Using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and cannot contact Oracle for support as the free tier doesn't include it.

I have tried opening ports by specifying them, and just opening all ports (to be clear this is not what I intend to do, I am just attempting to get them to open at all) and no matter what settings I use.

Port Configuration

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you update the firewall on the server OS?

Answer (score 1):

@pmdba is correct, and you should check the local firewall rules.

On ubuntu, the rules are saved in /etc/iptables/rules.v4

If you want to open port 80/TCP, you can edit this file and include the following:

-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Remember to add it before:

-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

This rule rejects everything.

After that:

sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4

You can also run iptables manually to add the desired rule(s), and once you are satisfied, save it. Remember to save and make a backup before :). You can save using:

sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4